# If $G$ and $H$ are two graphs, then what does $G \Delta H$ indicate in graph theory?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, notation, discrete-optimization

I came across this notation in a book titled "Combinatorial Optimization
Theory and Algorithms" by Bernhard Korte and Jens Vygen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an index of notations in the book on page 573. If you look up "$\Delta$" in it, you see that this is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of sets:
$$X \mathbin\Delta Y = (X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X).$$

It does not appear to be an operation on graphs, just on sets.

Comment: When applied to graphs, one presumes one should carry out the operation on the edge-sets.